# Centering a row of divs

Tags: css, html

I am having some difficulty sussing out a relatively easy thing to do but cannot seem to get my head around it no matter what I try I cannot get my DIV's to sit centrally inside a section.

So here goes...

```
<section>

<div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; float: left; text-align:center;">

<div style="float: left;"><span class="circle">test</span></div>
<div style="float: left;"><span class="circle">test</span></div>
<div style="float: left;"><span class="circle">test</span></div>
<div style="float: left;"><span class="circle">test</span></div>
<div style="float: left;"><span class="circle">test</span></div>

</div>

</section>


.circle {
    border-radius: 200%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #3B5163;
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 0 40px 0 40px;
}
```

So I need them to be set apart with even margin and when the screen scaled down for them to almost stack on top of each other... But no matter what I change form here the divs stay to the left within the wrapping div and do not stack on scale down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div><span class="circle">test</span></div>
    <div><span class="circle">test</span></div>
    <div><span class="circle">test three></span></div>
    <div><span class="circle">test</span></div>
    <div><span class="circle">test</span></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

You can use `text-align: center`, like you did, but for that to work, the divs have to be inline or inline-block elements, like this:

```
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
.container div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

You can add those properies in `style` attributes, like you did, but in most cases it's better to add it in separate css files.

Comment: you forgot to close the 3rd span + ur code doesnt seem to work, can you provide a fiddle example?

Comment: Ah sorry that was edited on the fly - as for a fiddle I can provide one yes bare with me.

Comment: Yes. http://jsfiddle.net/MLTRF/ It seems to work, though. Third span indeed isn't closed (I just copied that, and didn't notice). But although it isn't nice, it shouldn't cause problems for real life usage.

Comment: you forgot to add his .circle class to the fiddle :P but it works anyhow so +1 from me

Comment: Yes, I didn't think that was very important. I've added it now, and saw some issues with it (due to the margins and sized of the circles). I've corrected that as well: http://jsfiddle.net/MLTRF/1/ The one with the wider text is more elliptical, but since I don't know how it was supposed to look, I didn't pay any attention to that.

Comment: Ok so taking the advice from above I have come to this.

http://jsfiddle.net/iamdanbarrett/8GXKJ/

It seems to be all over the place? I literally just need the circles - what looks to be a simple icon of a tablet with an icon on top and some text underneath - but when when scaling it seem to be a bit all over the place - and for some reason the circles do not see to like height or width im having to use padding to create the size?